# How do I carry an Id from one view to another, in ASP.NET MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How do I carry my id(the '27' in the URL, to the next view)

URL in my first view:

```
http://localhost:11956/Forum/Details/27
```

In this view i open a new view with ActionLink, but the new window doesn't have the id. This is where I stranded. Can I chance `@Url-id...` to something else, or is it better to handle it in the C# ForumContrller, and if yes, how can that be done?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Post reply", "CreateTopicMessage" , new { id=@Url-id... })
```

Comment: I can add the code for the views and the controllers if needed.

Comment: @rqdbyx, you should provide a step-by-step description of how you solved it as an answer to this (your own) question, that way anyone else with a similar problem will know what to do. Also, it means that this question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for the `{id}` parameter in your route is stored in the `RouteData` collection. This can be accessed from the View like so:

```
@ViewContext.RouteData["id"]
```

So your code should read:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Post reply", "CreateTopicMessage" , new { id= ViewContext.RouteData["id"] })
```

Although, I'd seriously suggest you assign that id to a property of your model in the Controller action, as your View really shouldn't have any dependencies or knowledge of routing. Something like:

```
class ForumController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Detail(int id)
    {
        Forum model = LoadForumById(id);
        return View(model); // Forum has an "Id" property
    }
}
```

And then the action link code in your view would be:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Post reply", "CreateTopicMessage" , new { id = Model.Id })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is just a bit off:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
"Post Reply",
"CreateTopicMessage", 
"Forum", //I'm guessing here
 new { id = @Url-id }, //assign your route value
 null //for html attributes, it can be left null
)
```

Comment: The "@Url-id" or my "@Url-id..." can't compile. I wrote it as a kind of placeholder, where I thought something else you stand instead. Your solution didn't add anything as far as I can see, sorry.